# Как останавливать выполнение программы питон запущенной из другого файла в python?

Tags: python, exec

Подскажите как остановить выполнение программы запущенной из дгугого файла через `exec(open("file.py").read())` Тоесть есть два файла, например `main.py`, из которого запускается `file.py`. Вопрос есть ли такая же команда остановки для `file.py` из `main.py`

Comment: Проще не через exec запускать, а обернуть код в запускаемом файле в функцию, импортировать эту функцию в первом файле, запускать в отдельно потоке. Поток без проблем можно "прибить" в любой момент.

Comment: subprocess нужен тебе. там ты сможешь отправить сигнал завершения.

Comment: а как примерно это будет выглядеть через subprocess?